# Rotate a point using transformation matrix

Tags: c#, opencv

How rotate a point using transformation matrix?

```
 var point = new PointF(100, 150);
 var center = new PointF(100, 100);
 var angle = 45;

 var rotateMat = Cv2.GetRotationMatrix2D(new Point2f(center.Y, center.X), angle, 1);
 ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var point = new PointF(100, 150);
var center = new PointF(100, 100);
var angle = 45;

var rotateMat = Cv2.GetRotationMatrix2D(new Point2f(center.Y, center.X), angle, 1);
var resultPoint = (rotateMat * point.ToMat()).ToMat().ToPointF();

static class Hlp
{
  public static PointF ToPointF(this Mat mat)
  {
    return new PointF((float)mat.Get<double>(1, 0), (float)mat.Get<double>(0, 0));
  }
  public static Mat ToMat(this PointF point)
  {
    return new Mat(3, 1, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] { point.Y, point.X, 1 });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I lack the rep to comment.
The previous answer is mostly correct however the Point class is expecting x as the first argument (might just be the nuget package I am using).
So I needed a slight alteration:

```
static class Hlp
{
  public static PointF ToPointF(this Mat mat)
  {
    return new PointF((float)mat.Get<double>(0, 0), (float)mat.Get<double>(1, 0));
  }
  public static Mat ToMat(this PointF point)
  {
    return new Mat(3, 1, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] { point.X, point.Y, 1 });
  }
}
```

I am surprised that everything worked rotating a rectangle about its centre, it was only when I was rotating by a large enough amount about a specific point that I  noticed it wasn't quite right